# select particular item and give the saved data

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my application, i want that when i select a particular item from list it gives the saved data of it, as each item is a field that have some data. how can i do this???

My java code is:

```
 public void Onclick_click4(final TextView task_detail_txt)
{
    final TextView txtbox = (TextView) task_detail_txt ;

    if(task_detail_txt.getId()==R.id.textView4)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Task Details");

        ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
        final String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Ticket Number", "Job Performed", "Date and Time", "GPS-Latitude", "GPS-Longitude", "Status", "Next Due on" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
        modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

        builder.setItems(stringArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stringArray[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 txtbox.setText(stringArray[item]);
                 System.out.println("Item is: "+stringArray[item]);
                 /*CONTRY_ID = con.get(item).getCountryId();
                 stateET.requestFocus();*/
            }
         });


    builder.show();


           }

}
```

As i want that when i click on ticket Number it gives me the number that is saved in another activity. etc

Answer (score 0):

If you extend `ListActivity`, you can override `onListItemClick`, and retrive data in this way:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adpter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)l.getAdapter();
    String data = l.getItem(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)